# "ng-repeat" inside a "ui-view" causes a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null" exception [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I am trying to have a part of a parent's view change as the user descends into one of the parent's sub-states.

The following is a short code snippet to demonstrate my intention and the resulting exception.

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myModule">

<body>
    <div data-ui-view>
        Type Info: {{ typeInfo }}
        <div data-ui-view>
            <button data-ng-repeat="type in tArray" data-ng-click="changeT(type)">
                {{ type.desc }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script>
        var module = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router']);

        module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
            function testType(description, color) {
                this.desc = description;
                this.color = color;
            }

            $scope.tArray = [
                new testType('First', 'red'),
                new testType('2nd', 'blue'),
                new testType('Third (3rd)', 'green')
            ];

            $scope.typeInfo = {};

            $scope.changeT = function(typeObj) {
                $scope.typeInfo.t = typeObj;
                $state.go('.childState');
            };
        });

        module.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/");

            $stateProvider
                .state('root', {
                    url: '/',
                    controller: 'MyCtrl'
                })
                .state('root.childState', {
                    url: '/child',
                    template: 'I am the child!<button ui-sref="root">root</button>'
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It seems to have to do with the "ng-repeat" inside the "ui-view". If I remove the "ng-repeat", the exception doesn't occur. Interestingly, if I comment out the declaration of "$scope.tArray", the exception also doesn't occur.

A JSFiddle of the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cdvhmxp0/4/

The exception can be seen using Chrome. In Firefox, it seems to throw a "Error: parentNode is null" exception instead. Functionally, however, the code seems to be working as intended.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

I am relatively new to AngularJS so please feel free to let me know if I'm doing things in a contrived, non-idiomatic, or illogical way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem here is that right now you try to define template twice for child ui-view. First time in config and second time in html. Instead of defining one child state, you could define two of them to achieve default view and set root state as an abstract one without url. I've modified your code, it has no error now:

```
<div data-ng-app="myModule">
    <div data-ui-view>
        Type Info: {{ typeInfo }}

        <div data-ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var module = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router']);

        module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
            function testType(description, color) {
                this.desc = description;
                this.color = color;
            }

            $scope.tArray = [
                new testType('First', 'red'),
                new testType('2nd', 'blue'),
                new testType('Third (3rd)', 'green')
            ];

            $scope.typeInfo = {};

            $scope.changeT = function(typeObj) {
                $scope.typeInfo.t = typeObj;
                $state.go('root.childState');
            };
        });

        module.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

            $stateProvider
                .state('root', {
                    controller: 'MyCtrl',
                    abstract: true
                })
                .state('root.default', {
                    url: '/',
                    template: '<button data-ng-repeat="type in tArray" data-ng-click="changeT(type)">{{ type.desc }}</button>'
                })
                .state('root.childState', {
                    url: '/child',
                    template: 'I am the child!<button ui-sref="root.default">root</button>'
                });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I apologize for late response. I just wanted to let you know that this solved the issue!